# Como habilitar la creación de sistemas operativos de 64 bits en virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

la placa de mi pc es B450 Aorus M. tengo el problema que cuando quiero agregar un sistema operativo de 64 bits en virtualbox solo puedo crear el de 32 bits.

Comment: Tienes que habilitar una opcion en Windows(si usas winsows,  que no lo has puesto) te recomiendo que mires este articulo [habilitar 64 bits](https://www.tecnicomo.com/software/como-habilitar-virtualbox-64-bits-en-windows-10/). Si te resuelve la duda avisame y la pongo como respuesta para los demas! Un saludo

Comment: gracias por responder amigo. El articulo que compartes es complementario a lo que estaba buscando. y todo bien. En mi caso lo resolví habilitando el SVM mode en la Bios y al arrancar mi pc ya se visualizaba los de 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione el problema cambiando la configuración en la Bios en  mi  PC.
Ingrese en configuración de Windows 10 / recuperación / Inicio avanzado (reiniciar ahora) / Elegir una opción / Solucionar problemas / opciones avanzadas / Configuracion de firmware UEFI (reiniciar para que cargue el Bios)/ M.I.T. / Advanced Frequency Settings / Advanced CPU Core Settings / SVM mode  Enabled. La solución solo era habilitar el "SVM Mode".
* Segun busque, la solución es parecida en otros modelos.